# Good in-app purchase SDK for non-Google Play markets

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Our game relies on in-app purchases. Currently they use the Google's own system for that. But we get many requests from smaller app markets around the world to put our game there. But not having in-app purchases would seriously cripple the game mechanics.

But from what I've searched, there doesn't seem to be good alternatives. Amazon has it's own, but it's in invite only beta phase. Samsung apparently has it's own.. I would love to find a simple micropayment SDK to use in all these smaller app markets.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about Paypal? They have a nice SDK. It depends what features you need!

Comment: I have few items that can be bought unlimited times and single "managed item" (full game) that can be bought only once and should be remembered after reinstall.

Comment: Your app will probably get banned from Google Pay if it uses PayPal or any other payment system. Read the agreement: http://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal should work, although you will need to do some work to implement managed items on your own server. Some of the major 'smaller' markets have their own API on top of PayPal.

BTW, Amazon's in-app purchase library has been publicly available for a while: http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2012/04/announcing-the-in-app-purchasing-api-for-kindle-fire-and-other-android-devices.html